# I can't read the second string, no matter how many getchar i insert

Tags: c, string, getchar

This program need to read two strings, this two strings will be passed to the "confirm" function, they will be read and the the function will have to find a word in common.

But in the main i cant read the "string2" string! No matter how many getchar i insert.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void confirm(char string1[],char string2[]){

    char word[20];
    char w_aux[20];
    int i, j, k, l, m;
    int len1, len2;
    int find;

    i = 0; 

    len1 = strlen(string1);
    len2 = strlen(string2);

    while (i < len1){
        j = 0;

        while ((string1[i] != ' ') && (i < len1)){
            word[j] = string1[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        word[j] = '\0';
        k = 0;
        find = 0;
        while((k < len2) && (find == 0)){ 

            l = 0;
            while ((string2[k] != ' ') && (k < len2)){
                w_aux[l] = string2[k];
                k++;
                l++;
            }
            w_aux[l] = '\0';        
            if (j == l){
                m = 0;
                while((word[m] == w_aux[m]) && (m<j)){
                    m++;
                }
                if (m == j){
                    find = 1;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", word);
}

int main (){

    char string1[20];
    char string2[20];

    printf("Type the first text: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", string1);

    printf("Type the second text: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", string2);
    getchar();


    confirm(string1, string2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the `s` doing in the `scanf()` format?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  You should show input and output, as well as the results of the debugging you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getchar` after input of string 1 for `\n`:

```
printf("Type the first text: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]", string1);

getchar(); //here

printf("Type the second text: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]", string2);
```

Comment: @MateusLuiz As after input of string1 you press '\n' newline which is accepted by string2 and program terminates ,to accept this trailing newline we use `getchar()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the format specifier to `"%19[^\n]*c"`, it will take the trailing `'\n'` character away.